# How to draw a simple graph?

Tags: java

So here's the thing, I'm supposed to read a document and import some data.
A line in the document looks like this "A 0 2 5 20 23 25." (.txt).

I can write a method that finds this line and the values but my problem is to draw the actual graph whith the values. X of the graph will be fixed for 10 between each value and the values in the file corresponds to Y. I want to come up with a method that takes the first Y(0), and Draws a straight line to the next Y(2) and from 2-5 etc. 
I fail to do this, my method only Draws a line from 0-2 and 5-20 and 23-25.
Book hasn't talked about array's yet so I should do this without arrays, I try to do it as I read the file but..

Here is a bit of my code anyway, any tips?? Much appreciated

```
public static void drawGraph(String letter, Scanner input, Graphics g){
   while (input.hasNextLine()){
     int x = 1;
     String text = input.nextLine();
     Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
     String foundLetter = data.next();       
     if(foundLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(letter)){
        while(data.hasNextInt()){                 
           int count = data.nextInt();
            //This is where I get Stuck

            g.drawLine((x-1)*10, y1, 10*x);
            x++;

          }

     }
  }
```

}

I have made an template drawingpanel for the plot divided into sections of 10's

Thanks,

Comment: There seem to be missing some code in your example (what is y1, where is count used... )

Comment: The y1 was only a leftover from one of my attempts to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to memorize the last *y* value, then draw a line from *(x-1, last y)* to *(x, y)*.

```
int lastY = data.nextInt();
while (data.hasNextInt()) {                 
    int nextY = data.nextInt();
    g.drawLine((x-1)*10, lastY, 10*x, nextY);
    x++;
    lastY = nextY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yea, this what I realized I has to do but I used a for loop instead but this works too, thanks!